# Which package contains poly.transform()?

Tags: r

Obviously I'm too blind and/or stupid..   where is the function poly.transform() to extract the regression parameters out of a polynomial regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can find online points to [‹splusUtils›](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.3.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/splusUtils/poly.transform.html) from the [TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-enterprise-runtime-for-r), which is a commercial product.